# Select each element inside parent that parent is a variable

Tags: jquery

How i can select each element having a specific class name inside a parent where the  parent refers to a variable.

For example:

```
$('.tenUnit').each(function(index, element){

    //below element is a parent that is a variable
    $('element .specifyClass').each(function(index2, element2){
        // ... some code ...
    });
});
```

```
<div class="tenUnit"><!-- parent 1 -->
    <div>
        <input class="specifyClass"> <!-- can be anywhere inside div.tenUnit -->
    </div>
    <input class="specifyClass"><!-- can be anywhere inside div.tenUnit -->
</div>

<div class="tenUnit"><!-- parent 2 -->
    <div>
        <input class="specifyClass"> <!-- can be anywhere inside div.tenUnit -->
    </div>
    <input class="specifyClass"><!-- can be anywhere inside div.tenUnit -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use $(element).find('.specifyClass')

Comment: I first try and use your answer, its fast.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [jQuery selector context](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery1)

> By default, selectors perform their searches within the DOM starting
>   at the document root. However, an alternate context can be given for
>   the search by using the optional second parameter to the $() function.
>   For example, to do a search within an event handler, the search can be
>   restricted like so:

```
$('div.foo').click(function() {
  $('span', this).addClass('bar');
});
```

> When the search for the span selector is restricted to the context of
>   this, only spans within the clicked element will get the additional
>   class.
>
> Internally, selector context is implemented with the .find() method,
>   so $('span', this) is equivalent to $(this).find('span').

In your example, you can use `$(element)` as context.